# Question concerning Gauss' Theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> $\begin{cases}-\Delta u=0 & in\  B(0,2)\\u(x,y)=3xy+2 & on \ \partial B(0,2)\end{cases}$, then compute $u(0)$

I have the solution (skip the first $4$ lines, it is the justification of the mean value theorem)  but it is not clear for me how to choose $v$ and $n$. Of course their product should coincide with the function on the boundary but does for example $n$ have to be symmetric w.r. to $x$ and $y$ ?

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is not yours to define, it is dictated by the geometry of the domain. That is, $n(x,y)=(x,y)/2$ is the unit outward normal to the disk of radius $2$, which you have to use in order to apply the divergence theorem. Only $v$ is chosen by the author.